# MySQL query optimization. Avoiding copy to temporary & filesort

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Currently I have a table with close to 7 million rows

My main concern is that the query is using a temporary table and filesort. How could I go about optimizing this query?

MYSQL Query :

```
select count(category) as c_count, category 
from DemoTable 
where   
title like "%red" 
AND 
price != '0' 
group by category
```

Explain Output :

```
select_type : SIMPLE 
table : DemoTable
type : ALL
possible_keys : price
key : NULl
key_len NULL
ref : NULL
rows : 7020242
Extra : Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Can possible remove the temp table using a Dependent Subquery ??If yes than how can i use depedent subquery ??

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE table` or show indexes.

Comment: @Mihai already create indexes for price and category column

Comment: A composite index on(title,price,category) might help for a similar query but the wildcard at the beginning will not use ANY index.

Comment: @Mihai I am use match against instead of wildcard like (Fulltext index)

Comment: The leading % will render that column useless for indexing (and not sure a full text index will be that efficient either), while I suspect that most rows have a price that is not 0 so an index on that is likely useless for this query. Index on category should help though